# Easiest way to target parent Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code :

```js
$(a).parent().parent().parent().addClass('ITWORKS');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <span>
      <a href="#">
        Hello world
      </a>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Instead of writing this long line of code, How can I target the `div` only with the link

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `.closest('div.conatiner')`

See the [docs of .closest() here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).